# Can you figure out these Tom Swifties?

Tags: wordplay, english

A Tom Swifty is a pun involving somebody saying something in a particular manner reminiscent of the thing being said. For example, from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Swifty) for Tom Swifty:

> "I'll have a martini," Tom said **dryly**.
>
> "I think I'm a frog," Tom **croaked**.

The following Swifties have had their punny phrases replaced with *synonyms* of the puns themselves. Can you figure out the original words and make yourselves groan?

1. "I have an eighth note," Tom said **trembling**.
2. "I can't find my underpants," Tom said **shortly**.
3. "I really hope I get a 7 or 11," Tom said **riskily**.
4. "I never decrease as I move right," Tom said **boringly**.
5. "I can't go below this rope, it's too hard," Tom said **uncertainly**.
6. "I have an unnatural view of my buttocks," Tom said **retrospectively**.
7. "I baked this bread using a substitute grain," Tom said with a **dramatic gesture**.
8. "I'm protesting to the singer who popularized Autotune," Tom told the **meat man**.
9. "I'm the prince from Undertale," Tom said **in the role of Louis the Métis rioter**.
10. "I feel like I'm creating part of a play," Tom said while **taking a standardized test**.
11. "I've come up with a new Conservative party member," Tom said while **listing down items**.
12. "I need to find a way to make this work with Apple's calendar app," Tom said **meticulously**.

Comment: #9 might be a bit unfair. I'll probably replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everybody's gotten partial answers, I'll make a CW to amalgamate the correct ones people have gotten so far:

1. Player One

> "I have an eighth note," Tom said **with a quaver**.

2. Player One

> "I can't find my underpants," Tom said **briefly**.

3. Player One

> "I really hope I get a 7 or an 11," Tom said **dicily**.

4. Deusovi

> "I never decrease as I move right," Tom said **monotonously**.

5. Alconja

> "I can't go below this rope, it's too hard," Tom said, **in limbo**.

6. Player One

> "I have an unnatural view of my buttocks," Tom said **in hindsight**.

7. Alconja

> "I baked this bread using a substitute grain," Tom said with a **flourish**.

8. Alconja

> "I'm protesting to the singer who popularized Autotune," Tom told the **butcher**.

9. Person

> "I'm the prince from Undertale," Tom said **as Riel**.

10. Deusovi

> "I feel like I'm creating part of a play," Tom said while **writing the ACT**.

11. shettysahab

> "I've come up with a new Conservative party member," Tom said while **taking inventory**.

12. Deusovi

> "I need to find a way to make this work with Apple's calendar app," Tom said **methodically**.

Comment: 10. "I feel like I'm creating part of a play," Tom said while taking the ACT(American College Testing).

Comment: @shettysahab Oops, I forgot to put that one in. Somebody already got it.

Comment: "I've come up with a new Conservative party member," Tom said while preparing an invenTory. Conservative party was formed from the Tory party.

Answer (score 2):

1.

> with a quaver

4.

> monotonously

6.

> on reflection

7.

> flourish

10.

> writing the ACT

12

> methodically

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer for ones that I don't think any one else has got right first:

1

> "I have an eighth note," Tom said **with a quaver**

2.

> "I can't find my underpants," Tom said **briefly**

3.

> "I really hope I get a 7 or 11," Tom said **dicily**

6.

> "I have an unnatural view of my buttocks," Tom said **in hindsight**

11.

> <del>"I've come up with a new Conservative party member," Tom said while **making [a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-List_%28Conservative%29)**</del>

Comment: The correct answer to #1 is actually three words. You have the important word right, though.

Comment: Also the correct answer to #6 is two words.

Comment: Deusovi has the correct answer to #4.

Comment: @JoeZ haha damn that's what I meant to change it to in the first place :)

Comment: You know what would have made it harder? If I'd changed it to "half-trembling" and "eighth note" to "sixteenth note". Then it would be "with a semiquaver".

Comment: @JoeZ.: Or you could just go all the way to "hemidemisemiquaver".

Comment: @JoeZ how's 6 now? also 11?

Comment: #11 not quite. Also, since you've been trying so hard for #6 I'll just give it to you: "in hindsight".

Comment: @JoeZ Damn, I really though I had it with 11 there :)

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer**:

1, "I have an eighth note," Tom said **trembling**.

> "I have an eighth note," Tom said **with a quaver**.

5, "I can't go below this rope, it's too hard," Tom said **uncertainly**.

> "I can't go below this rope, it's too hard," Tom said, **in limbo**.

6, "I have an unnatural view of my buttocks," Tom said **retrospectively**.

> <del>"I have an unnatural view of my buttocks," Tom said **looking back**.</del>

7, "I baked this bread using a substitute grain," Tom said with a **dramatic gesture**.

> "I baked this bread using a substitute grain," Tom said with a **wry expression**.

8, "I'm protesting to the singer who popularized Autotune," Tom told the **meat man**.

> "I'm protesting to the singer who popularized Autotune," Tom told the **butcher**.

Comment: @JoeZ. - can it replace any part of it (i.e. part of the quote, or the adverb itself?)

Comment: The correct answer will replace the bolded parts of the problem quotes.

Comment: You have the right word for #1, but you didn't phrase it correctly. The correct answer is actually three words long.

Comment: @JoeZ. - better?

Comment: Still not quite it for #4.

Comment: Think: you had boxers before, what are the other type?

Comment: @JoeZ. I see others have "briefly", but I think getting pantsed would have you wondering where your underpants are more... :P

Comment: "Briefly" was the answer I had, though. I guess it wasn't interesting enough :P

Answer (score 1):

9. "I'm the prince from Undertale," Tom said in the role of Louis the Métis rioter

> Tom said as Riel

Comment: I guess somebody got it after all.

Comment: The joke is as riel as it gets, right? ;)